# Can't install lua package using luarocks due to conflicting architecture

Tags: dll, lua, architecture, linker, luarocks

I'm getting the following error when trying to install the `lpeg` library using `luarocks`:

```
lptree.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol luaL_checkudata referenced in function lp_gc
C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\lib\lua5.1.lib : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'x86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'
lpeg.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 55 unresolved externals

Error: Build error: Failed installing lpeg.dll in C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\rocks/lpeg/1.0.2-1/lib
```

I'm using the following version of `lua`:

`Lua 5.1.5 Copyright (C) 1994-2012 Lua.org, PUC-Rio`

And the following version of `luarocks`:

```
luarocks 2.0.2
LuaRocks main command-line interface
```

I installed `lpeg` using the command provided [here](https://luarocks.org/modules/gvvaughan/lpeg) namely:

`luarocks install lpeg`

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: Download x64 lua, or configure luarocks to build x86 libraries.

Comment: I have this one: https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/Lua 

How do I determine whether it is x86 or x64?

Comment: It's x86, luarocks has told you: "library machine type 'x86'".

Comment: Allright, then how do I get x64 lua? I don't see any Windows installation instructions in https://lua.org/download.html

Comment: http://luabinaries.sourceforge.net/download.html